# How to handle DOM events of WebKit.NET control?

Tags: .net, webkit, browser, webkit.net

With System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control, we can use the following code to handle DOM event:

```
HtmlElement centerButton = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("centerButton");
centerButton.Click += this.WelcomeHandler_Click;
```

But while using WebKit.NET, WebKit.Dom.Element doesn't have a ".Click" event. How to handle DOM events like "WebBrowser" control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as now, unfortunately, WebKit.NET hasn't developt this feature yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use follow code to handle element event:

Create element

```
var doc = webKitBrowser1.Document;
doc.TextContent = "<h1>text</h1>";

var body = doc.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0];

var lnkBtn = webKitBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("a");
lnkBtn.SetAttribute("href", "app:dosome,by link");
lnkBtn.TextContent = "Link:Click me!";

var inpBtn = webKitBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("input");
inpBtn.SetAttribute("type", "button");
inpBtn.SetAttribute("onclick", "window.location.href='app:dosome,by button';");
inpBtn.SetAttribute("value", "Button:Click me!");

body.AppendChild(lnkBtn);
body.AppendChild(inpBtn);
```

Handle event

```
private void webKitBrowser1_Navigating(object sender
    , WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.Scheme == "app")
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show(e.Url.ToString());
    }
}
```

So, when you need to handle some event, just to Navigate to a custom protocol and handle it!

The code look like ugly but it's work! lol